# Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'CKRecordValue'

Tags: swift, cloudkit, swift3

With the update to Swift in the latest beta build this no longer works and I'm stumped. I probably need to add other things, I've tried changing the `let` to `var` and adding an `!` to the `recordType["username"]` and `password`. I am new to this, so any direction would be most grateful!

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func LoginTapped(sender: AnyObject){

        var recordType = CKRecord(recordType: "Login")

        recordType["username"] = username.text <-Cannot assign value
        recordType["password"] = password.text <-Cannot assign value

        publicDatabase.save(recordType) {
            (record, error) in

            if error == nil {       
                print("Created Successfully")
            }

            else {           
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error means that the type of `recordType["username"]` is `CKRecordValue`. You're trying to put a `String?` into a variable of type `CKRecordValue`. That doesn't work, the value you put in a variable must be of the correct type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
recordType["username"] = username.text! as NSString
recordType["password"] = password.text! as NSString
```

Comment: I can't test right now so you might have to tweak that a little. But the point is that you cannot automatically cross the bridge any longer from String to NSString, so you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much Matt! What I really want to do is to be able to create a login/Register for an App and use CloudKit instead of Parse. But I'm not finding a lot of info on it.

Comment: Just an FYI Matt, It wouldn't allow me to yesterday.. But thanks for the help!